# jasmine_node failed while running mean-seed

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, yeoman-generator, jasmine-node

Having trouble running a project generated by yeoman generator called mean-seed. I've been tinkering with it for a few days now and tried a couple things. Where I am having trouble is running the "jasmine_node" task:

```
Running "jasmine_node" task
>> Error: Unable to access jarfile node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar
Warning: Done, with errors. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

So I first tried identifying missing npm packages to install

```
  744  npm install && bower update && bower install
  755  npm install protractor
  760  npm install npm install selenium-standalone
  761  npm install -g protractor
  765  npm install protractor-tester
  767  npm install protractor-selenium-server-vagrant
  768  npm install selenium-standalone@2.39.0-2.8.0-2
```

none of these actually created the file selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar in the node_modules directory. I ran a find to check, however several other jars were install.

```
$ find . -name "*.jar" -print
./node_modules/grunt-jasmine-node-coverage-validation/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters/ext/jline.jar
./node_modules/grunt-jasmine-node-coverage-validation/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters/ext/js.jar
./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/2.39.0/server.jar
```

I found the selenium server download so I tried downloading and copying it over to the referenced directory which I had to create
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar

I run grunt again. It goes through tasks then runs the jasmine_node task

```
Running "jasmine_node" task
TEST configFile: /Users/jgs/Projects/mean/app/test/../configs/config.test.json
configFile: ./app/configs/config.test.json
   info  - socket.io started
waiting for server to be running..
[success] connected to db at localhost:27017/test_temp
>> Feb 01, 2014 3:03:54 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
>> INFO: Launching a standalone server
>> Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver

------------------
[ERROR]
Run `node run.js config=test`
Server not connected. Ensure you have a node server running with the `config=test` command line option so this server connects to the TEST database - the same one used here for the tests. Do NOT connect to the live database for doing tests!
------------------

[success] connected to db at localhost:27017/test_temp

all tests - 2526 ms
    should test everything - 2525 ms

Failures:

  1) all tests should test everything
   Message:
     Expected 'ERROR - check the logs above to fix the problem then try again' to be false.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected 'ERROR - check the logs above to fix the problem then try again' to be false.
    at /Users/jgs/Projects/mean/app/test/all.spec.js:6:2935
    at _rejected (/Users/jgs/Projects/mean/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /Users/jgs/Projects/mean/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/jgs/Projects/mean/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jgs/Projects/mean/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Users/jgs/Projects/mean/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/jgs/Projects/mean/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Finished in 2.53 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped


Warning: Task "jasmine_node" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
$
```

Any idea why jasmine task is still failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`, see here for more info:
https://github.com/jackrabbitsgroup/generator-mean-seed/issues/5

I hadn't yet updated the documentation everywhere yet for the Protractor upgrade, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

First you need to download both the selenium-server-standalone
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar

and the chromedriver
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

copy them to

```
node_modules/protractor/selenium/
```

you will want another terminal tab or window to start the node server by runing

```
node run.js
```

then you can run the default grunt task

```
grunt
```

You will then see the output of the selenium tests in the console and chrome should open and perform the tests automatically.